# Azure Service Fabric Message Queue

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to queue a series of tasks and run them asynchronously using Azure Service Fabric. I am currently using the CloudMessageQueue with worker roles. I am trying to migrate to Service Fabric. From the worker roles, here is my code:

```
    private void ExecuteTask()
    {
        CloudQueueMessage message = null;

        if (queue == null)
        {
            jmaLogProvider.WriteToLog(new ErrorMessage(MessageSeverity.Error, String.Format("Queue for WorkerRole2 is null. Exiting.")));
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            message = queue.GetMessage();
            if (message != null)
            {
                JMATask task = GetTask(message.AsString);
                string msg = (message == null) ? string.Empty : message.AsString;
                //jmaLogProvider.WriteToLog(new ErrorMessage(MessageSeverity.JMA, String.Format("Executing task {0}", msg)));
                queue.DeleteMessage(message);
                PerformTask(task);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = (message == null) ? string.Empty : message.AsString;
            jmaLogProvider.WriteToLog(new ErrorMessage(MessageSeverity.Error, String.Format("Message {0} Error removing message from queue {1}", msg, ex.ToString())));
        }
    }
```

I have some questions:

1. How do I run the perform task method asynchronously? I want to run about 30 - 40 tasks at the same time.
2. I have a list of JMATask. How do I add the list to a queue?
3. Does the list need to be added to a queue?

   ```
   namespace Stateful1
   {
      public class JMATask
      {
        public string Name { get; set; }
      }

   /// <summary>
   /// An instance of this class is created for each service replica by the Service Fabric runtime.
   /// </summary>
   internal sealed class Stateful1 : StatefulService
   {
   public Stateful1(StatefulServiceContext context)
       : base(context)
   { }

   /// <summary>
   /// Optional override to create listeners (e.g., HTTP, Service Remoting, WCF, etc.) for this service replica to handle client or user requests.
   /// </summary>
   /// <remarks>
   /// For more information on service communication, see http://aka.ms/servicefabricservicecommunication
   /// </remarks>
   /// <returns>A collection of listeners.</returns>
   protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
   {
       return new ServiceReplicaListener[0];
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// This is the main entry point for your service replica.
   /// This method executes when this replica of your service becomes primary and has write status.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="cancellationToken">Canceled when Service Fabric needs to shut down this service replica.</param>
   protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
       // TODO: Replace the following sample code with your own logic 
       //       or remove this RunAsync override if it's not needed in your service.

       IReliableQueue<JMATask> tasks = await this.StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableQueue<JMATask>>("JMATasks");
       //var myDictionary = await this.StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, long>>("myDictionary");

       while (true)
       {
           cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

           using (var tx = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction())
           {
               var result = await tasks.TryDequeueAsync(tx);

               //how do I execute this method async?
               PerformTask(result.Value);

               //Create list of JMA Tasks to queue up
               await tasks.EnqueueAsync(tx, new JMATask());

               //var result = await myDictionary.TryGetValueAsync(tx, "Counter");

               //ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this, "Current Counter Value: {0}",
               //    result.HasValue ? result.Value.ToString() : "Value does not exist.");

               //await myDictionary.AddOrUpdateAsync(tx, "Counter", 0, (key, value) => ++value);

               // If an exception is thrown before calling CommitAsync, the transaction aborts, all changes are 
               // discarded, and nothing is saved to the secondary replicas.
               await tx.CommitAsync();
           }

           await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
       }
   }

   private async void PerformTask(JMATask task)
   {
       //execute task
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Struggling with similar issue and this was helpful, thanks.  Curious what you ended up with and how it worked for you.

Comment: I used another technology: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568104.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RunAsync method should not have this line code: `await tasks.EnqueueAsync(tx, new JMATask());`

Create list of JMA Tasks to queue up should be another method in your stateful service which looks like this:

```
    public async Task AddJMATaskAsync(JMATask task)
    {
        var tasksQueue = await StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableQueue<JMATask>>("JMATasks");
        using (var tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                await tasksQueue.EnqueueAsync(tx, request);
                await tx.CommitAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tx.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
```

And then your PerformTask method can contain a call to a stateless microservice:

```
    public async Task PerformTask (JMATask task)
    {
        //1. resolve stateless microservice URI
        // statelessSvc

        //2. call method of the stateless microservice
        // statelessSvc.PerformTask(task);
    }
```

So basically, the stateful service will only queue and dequeue the tasks. Performing the actual task can be done by a microservice which will be available to all nodes in the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of Tasks and then do await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

That's probably the easiest direct answer.

However - if each task is something slightly different, have you considered creating individual micro services for each of the tasks?

Comment: Yes, each task is different. How do I create individual micro services?

Comment: Ideally create one service (stateful, stateless) for each task. It's hard to answer exactly without a deeper understanding, but that would be my gut reaction. Each service should have a simple single responsibility and be really good at doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I updated my post. The tasks move data from one system to another. There are several hundred different tasks, but many of them perform the same type of action.

Comment: You probably want a combination of IReliableQueue for incoming tasks and IReliableDictionary to keep track of currently processing tasks. Use one task to dequeue from the queue and initiate processing, keeping track of processing the dictionary. On startup process anything not yet finished from the dictionary before the queue. Remember to cancel when required as well to prevent hanging tasks!